# Angular application's localStorage not working in Android web view

Tags: android, angular, webview, local-storage, android-webview

I have created a web application in **Angular 4**.

In the application after login, I am saving user security token in **localStorage**

Based on the localStorage value I am hiding few links in the application like - hiding the login button after successful login and it works fine in the browser. but when I tried to load it in **native android app web view** that hides logic not working.

> Link Hide Code Html

```
<a *ngIf="checkToken()" (click)="onLogOut()">Logout</a>
```

> Angular Component Code

```
checkToken() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) 
    {
        return false;                    
    } 
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Android Web View Code

```
web.loadUrl(URL)
```

I already search a lot on it but not found any solution, Please suggest or give me a way to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebView in your app, did you enable the feature by setting Android WebView like:

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

And maybe you need to call the following as well:

```
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try enable the localStorage in Android web setting

```
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```